# ZF2 Form validation - non-overlapping dates and times

Tags: php, html, validation, zend-framework2

I'm currently working on a meeting system using ZF2. I use two models for this, called 'meeting' and 'meetingTime'.
Meeting has a one-to-many relationship with MeetingTime.

Meeting contains the following fields related to dates/times:

```
public $slotDuration;
public $meetingTimes;
```

SlotDuration is the time of each meeting in minutes. MeetingTimes contains MeetingTime objects.

MeetingTime has the following fields related to dates/times:

```
    public $slots;
    public $dateTimeStart;
```

Slots is the amount of meetings that should be in this 'block' of meetings. DateTimeStart is self-explanatory. To determine the end time of this meeting, we take the slot duration and multiply it by the amount of slots in this meetingtime object. Since each block of meetings may end at a different time, this is done in the meetingtime object. The result is then converted to a DateTime object.

In the creation form, we dynamically add new fieldsets for meetingTimes if the user thinks it is necessary. Our business model is made to be as flexible as possible, so the user may have pauses between meetings or stretch it out over multiple days if need be. Each single fieldset contains a HTML5 DateTime element for the start date and time, an HTML5 Number element for the slots and a selectbox for the room to be reserved. These fieldsets are enclosed in another fieldset, enclosed in the form.

Now, my question is, concerning validation, how do I make sure that NONE of these times overlap (they have to be consecutive)? I create the objects in the controller before sending the information to the database, maybe this might be of use. 
I hope I can use the ZF2 validation pipeline for this, but if that isn't possible, I'm open for any other solution.

EDIT:
The form looks like this, by the way.
http://puu.sh/9yJri/12422b8231.png

Comment: Are meetings linked to a location or is there no resource ie room?

Comment: @JonDay The meetings themselves are not linked to a location. MeetingTimes are linked to a location, in order to allow different meetings to be held in different rooms.

Thank you for your response, by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't write this properly without way more information but you're going to need to write a custom validator which will be a bit like this:

LocationAvailabilityValidator.php

```
    <?php
    namespace MeetingModuleThang\Validator;

    use Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator;

    class LocationAvailabilityValidator extends AbstractValidator

    /**
 * (non-PHPdoc)
 * @see Zend\Validator.ValidatorInterface::isValid()
 */
public function isValid($value, $context=array())
{
          //Get the location object from db by name
          $location = $this->getObjectManager()->findByName('\Application\Entity\Location', $context['location']);

          //Get your datetime of end properly this is likely ridiculous
          // But I don't know the metrics and types you are using 
          $endTime = $value + $slotDuration;

          $meetingStartDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat($yourFormat, $value);
          $meetinEndDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat($yourFormat, $endTime);

          return $location->isAvailableBetween($meetingStart, $meetingEnd);
    }
```

Then you can just check in the location method if slots exist for that object in db

Comment: Can't vote up because of my reputation, but this approach works - thanks!